# Rcpp wrapper for the .C interface

Tags: c, r, build, rcpp, r-package

I help to maintain the R package [iRF](https://github.com/cran/iRF). As you can see, it have been [using Rcpp](https://github.com/cran/iRF/blob/master/src/RcppExports.cpp) to call some [C functions](https://github.com/cran/iRF/blob/fc61c8d4e2739d7dd66301c5a848a444357af802/src/rf.c#L40-L55) via [the `.C` interface](https://github.com/cran/iRF/blob/fc61c8d4e2739d7dd66301c5a848a444357af802/R/randomForest.default.R#L255-L312) since its last release in 2017.

When I clone that repo and try to install it on my computer (running macOS Mojave) with the latest version of R and Rcpp, it installs successfully. However, any modification to the `src/` directory would change some MD5 hash and trigger an `Rcpp::compileAttributes`. Unfortunately, the recompiled attributes don't work with the legacy `.C` interface.

```sh
/tmp/iRF master#2.0.0
$ Rscript -e 'Rcpp::compileAttributes()'

/tmp/iRF master#2.0.0
$ R CMD INSTALL .
* installing to library ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library’
* installing *source* package ‘iRF’ ...
files ‘R/RcppExports.R’, ‘src/RcppExports.cpp’ have the wrong MD5 checksums
** using staged installation
** libs
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c ExportedFunctionsRIT.cpp -o ExportedFunctionsRIT.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include  -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c classTree.c -o classTree.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include  -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c init.c -o init.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c processNodes.cpp -o processNodes.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include  -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c regTree.c -o regTree.o
regTree.c:209:9: warning: unused variable 'jj' [-Wunused-variable]
    int jj, jold;
        ^
regTree.c:416:14: warning: unused variable 'dum' [-Wunused-variable]
        int i, tmp, dum;
                    ^
2 warnings generated.
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include  -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c regrf.c -o regrf.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include  -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c rf.c -o rf.o
rf.c:492:17: warning: expression result unused [-Wunused-value]
  ...+                                                          nrightimp[cl[n] - 1]++;
     ^                                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c rfsub.f -o rfsub.o
/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang -fopenmp -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include  -fPIC  -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe -c rfutils.c -o rfutils.o
clang++ -std=gnu++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1/lib/R/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib -o iRF.so ExportedFunctionsRIT.o RcppExports.o classTree.o init.o processNodes.o regTree.o regrf.o rf.o rfsub.o rfutils.o -L/usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/9/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/9.1.0 -L/usr/local/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/9 -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -L/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.1/lib/R/lib -lR -lintl -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/00LOCK-iRF/00new/iRF/libs
** R
** data
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘iRF’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/00LOCK-iRF/00new/iRF/libs/iRF.so':
  dlopen(/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/00LOCK-iRF/00new/iRF/libs/iRF.so, 6): Symbol not found: _iRF_RIT_1class
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/00LOCK-iRF/00new/iRF/libs/iRF.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/00LOCK-iRF/00new/iRF/libs/iRF.so
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/iRF’
* restoring previous ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.6/site-library/iRF’
```

It seems that Rcpp in 2019 has dropped the `.C` interface and supports `.Call` exclusively, but asking users to install ancient R and Rcpp versions isn't really practical. I understand that the best solution is probably rewriting the R and C code to use `.Call`, but the functions take tens of arguments and span hundreds of lines, so that is going to be tedious.

How can I get around with this issue?

Comment: Rcpp exists  since 2008 (or 2005 if you include RcppClassic) and has *never ever* supported the `.C()` interface.  I guess your package may have mixed Rcpp use (via .Call()) along with .C() calls you managed.

Comment: And I suspect the issue you are now having is with the init routines _which were imposed by R Core_ so in that sense you are shooting the messenger (ie Rcpp) here.  But I also just sent an email to someone working on Google Summer of Code updating another legacy package -- mixing `.C` and `.Call` _while using the autogenerated `init.c`_ can have issues.

Comment: On another note, the macOS install instructions need to be bumped :/ Those listed in the `README` are for R 3.x.0 - 3.3.y.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for the response! Do you think the only way to fix this issue is to spend days or even weeks to rewrite the whole `.C` code in `.Call`, or can I somehow "cheat" by tricking Rcpp into believing that the source hasn't changed (e. g. making the hash routine return the some value for any file)? A third way I can think of is writing a `.Call` wrapper in C++ that calls the original `.C` function in C, but as long as the wrapper stays in the same package, the file hash issue persists.

Comment: Also, and just to cover our bases here, we used to have a bug in `compileAttributes()` which _when converting an older file_ required running it twice.  But this was squashed in one of the more recent releases so if you are Rcpp 1.0.2 you should not have that issue.

Comment: I am trying to think it through (also for the GSoC project). I haven't had this issue myself in a while.  Focus maybe on two things: get this linking, so trace the symbol.  Then maybe try to not autogenerate RcppExports.cpp.   `.C()` has been deprecated for a loooong time so if you are still using you are paying a little tax here.  But we should still get it working.  Maybe come to the rcpp-devel list for help...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I have just updated to Rcpp 1.0.2, and it *almost* works! Except all exported functions are now prefixed with an underscore. For example, `.Call('iRF_RIT_1class', ...)` is changed to `.Call('_iRF_RIT_1class', ...)`, whereas `RcppExport SEXP iRF_RIT_1class(SEXP zSEXP, ...)` becomes `RcppExport SEXP _iRF_RIT_1class(SEXP zSEXP, ...)`. How weird... (I'm subscribing to the mailing list!)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Hi Dirk, I tried to subscribe to Rcpp-devel, but it has been 20 hours and I didn't see a confirmation email yet. I have also sent an email to `rcpp-devel@lists.r-forge.r-project.org` but it doesn't appear in the [Archives](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/) either. Are you sure that list open to the public?

Comment: I do not know. List are admin'ed by the Vienna folks via R-Forge.  The admin interface is up ...

Comment: I did send an email in July: http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/2019-July/thread.html  But I am not sure I got it delivered myself.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I can see it in the Archive web interface (as you do), so I would assume the subscribers had received it?

Comment: You may be on to something as I had similar worries earlier.  I started to enquire, will report back as / if I learn something.

Comment: Heard back, appears to be functioning, subscription attempt I sent to a not-used-for-mailing-lists accounts arrived, but was hidden in the spam folder.  Once I located it I successfully subscribed (once more) to rcpp-devel.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Just made yet another attempt to subscribe to the mailing list, and finally it works! Actually, the confirmation just appears in my inbox, and I have no idea why it didn't work the last time. Thank you sir!

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Did you guys end up getting this working? I know the .C interface is not encouraged (is it actually deprecated?), but mainly out of curiosity I have been trying to figure out how to mix both Rcpp and .C. Is it even possible to do this without hacking the auto-generated cpp files?

Comment: Don't use `.C()`, use `.Call()`.  That is a pretty broad consemsus.