# Avoid regenerating RcppExports when using devtools::test

Tags: r, rcpp, devtools, r-package, testthat

I'm maintaining a legacy codebase and am forced to use some dirty hack to get around some [game-breaking issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57366463/rcpp-wrapper-for-the-c-interface). The hack requires me to manually edit the `RcppExports` files. Yeah, this sounds stupid, but it works and I'm not going to change the interface very often anyway, so it sticks.

I test my package with `devtools::test`, which calls `testthat::test_dir` under the hood, which in turn calls `devtools::load_all` to "simulate what happens when a package is installed and loaded with `library()`". This somehow causes my handcrafted `RcppExports` files to be wiped out and replaced by some autogenerated stuff, leading to a lot of errors.

So I'm here, looking for another hack to fix the issue caused by a hack. Any suggestions?

Comment: Easiest solution is to avoid using `devtools::test` and manually triggering the test via `test_package()`.

Comment: @coatless Thanks. Note that you must `R CMD install --install-tests .` before doing `Rscript -e 'testthat::test_package("INSERT_PACKAGE_NAME_HERE")'`.

Comment: If you're editing the `RcppExports` files by hand anyway, then just delete all the `// [[Rcpp::export]]` directives, that way `compileAttributes` will stop overwriting the files each time.

Comment: @Alexis Not exactly. It deletes my `RcppExports` files :(

Comment: Then maybe renaming them is also necessary. The whole `Rcpp::export` mechanism is for sure optional, I don't use it in my packages.

Comment: @Alexis You mean renaming `RcppExports.cpp` to something else? I'm not sure how to do this. A quick search reveals no strings containing `"RcppExports"`, so I suspect if the names are hardcoded.

Comment: Yes, renaming that `cpp` file and deleting the directives, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/cran/iRF/blob/master/src/ExportedFunctionsRIT.cpp#L13).

Comment: @Alexis It works! You may want to make it into an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very well, as commented.
`Rcpp` attributes are those matching `// [[...]]`,
that's what `compileAttributes` looks for to decide which files to wtite/overwrite.
However, that whole mechanism is optional (though recommended).
If you have to switch to manual adjustments anyway, 
then you can remove the attributes and rename the previously generated exports. 
That way `Rcpp` will stop treating that code as something it created,
so it will stop updating/overwriting it.